# Accidentally moved Windows "My Videos" system folder to the %Userprofile% folder. Now it can't be renamed?

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

While moving some user folders from one harddrive back to the "default" location, I accidentally set the "My Videos" folder to be c:\Users[userprofile]

I managed to fix the Registry to rename the "My Video" key to c:\Users[userprofile]\My Videos, however the Userprofile folder itself in C:\Users still shows up in Explorer as "My Videos". I can't rename it in the folder properties (it is greyed out).

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Just happened to me today, too, with the "Saved Pictures" folder. I was already starting to think I was the only one this ever happened to... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the **My Videos** folder, go  to the *Location* tab, click on *Restore Default*, Ok your way out and reboot. That ought to fix the confusion.

Comment: So, I have already done that with the actual My Videos folder.  It now appears as it should under the %USERPROFILE% folder.

My issue is that the &USERPROFILE% folder remains named My Videos in Explorer.

Comment: Can you turn on the display of all hidden and protected OS files (Tools / Folder options / View tab) and check if there's a *desktop.ini* in the %UserProfile% folder? Delete that (or move it out from there), reboot and see if the issue's fixed.